# XSLT - XML to CSV - template vs. for-each - remove whitespace

Tags: xml, xslt, csv

(1) Why does Option1 (Template) produce whitespace (mainly btw rec1 & 5) whereas Option2 (ForEach) doesn't? 
 (2) If possible, how do I code Option1 to remove the resulting whitespace?
Assumptions: use of XSLT v1., XMLPad/Stylus for testing, MSXML4.
Working on processing larger, more complex XML input files (mix of elements/attributes) with multiple 'type' selection criteria to create multiple TSV output files.  A number of references seem to indicate using Templates as the preferable method.  Using match currently pushes too much whitespace to the message queue.

**XML:**

```
<main>
    <event>
        <event_type>Bike</event_type>
        <date>2012-02-05</date>
    </event>
    <event>
        <event_type>Run</event_type>
        <date>2012-02-06</date>
    </event>
    <event>
        <event_type>Swim</event_type>
        <date>2012-02-07</date>
    </event>
    <event>
        <event_type>Run</event_type>
        <date>2012-02-08</date>
    </event>
    <event>
        <event_type>Bike</event_type>
        <date>2012-02-09</date>
    </event>
</main>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:variable name="tab" select="'&#09;'" />

<xsl:template match="@*|text()"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text/>event<xsl:value-of select="$tab"/>
<xsl:text/>date<xsl:value-of select="$tab"/>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- OPTION1 -->
<xsl:template match="event[event_type='Bike']"><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="event_type"/><xsl:value-of select="$tab"/>
<xsl:value-of select="date"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- OPTION2 -->
<!--<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:for-each select="event[event_type='Bike']"><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="event_type"/><xsl:value-of select="$tab"/>
<xsl:value-of select="date"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>-->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output - Opt1 Template** (can't post pics yet, ... are whitespace)

event...date......
Bike....2012-02-05............
Bike....2012-02-09.

**Output - Opt2 ForEach**

event...date.....
Bike....2012-02-05
Bike....2012-02-09

Comment: I tried your example in VS 2010 Xml / Xslt editor and it works as expected with either option, no additional whitespace added. Could be XMLPad/Stylus or MSXML4 that adds additional spaces?

Comment: your solution works in VS 2010, I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: @dradu: Thanks, I thought you were the OP :)

Comment: @marcus: Doesn't my solution work in your environment?

Comment: dradu, dimitri: both correct on q2, dradu correct on q1 (XMLPad v3 creates spaces, uninstalled). Am new, broke rule on multiple q's. Learned cleaner syntax from Dimitri, would like to upvote both, thank you.  FWIW - To process my orig work file w/ StylusStudio ~320ms using Template, ~305ms using ForEach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried a different editor (Architag XRay Xml Editor, which uses MSXML) and to make it work I had to use CR/LF characters. I believe Dimitre's answer is right.
This is my modification:

```
<!-- OPTION1 -->
<xsl:template match="event[event_type='Bike']">
<xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="event_type"/><xsl:value-of select="$tab"/>
<xsl:value-of select="date"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You want this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vTab" select="'&#09;'" />
    <xsl:variable name="vNL" select="'&#10;'" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:value-of select=
        "concat(' event', $vTab, 'date', $vTab, $vNL)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="event[event_type='Bike']">
      <xsl:value-of select=
        "concat(' ', event_type, $vTab, date, $vNL)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<main>
    <event>
        <event_type>Bike</event_type>
        <date>2012-02-05</date>
    </event>
    <event>
        <event_type>Run</event_type>
        <date>2012-02-06</date>
    </event>
    <event>
        <event_type>Swim</event_type>
        <date>2012-02-07</date>
    </event>
    <event>
        <event_type>Run</event_type>
        <date>2012-02-08</date>
    </event>
    <event>
        <event_type>Bike</event_type>
        <date>2012-02-09</date>
    </event>
</main>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
 event  date    
 Bike   2012-02-05
 Bike   2012-02-09
```